# Why user can access object from other tablespace?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have altered a user to only be able to access two tablespaces,

```
alter user TEMP_USER quota unlimited on TEMP_USER_DAT;
alter user TEMP_USER quota unlimited on TEMP_USER_IDX;
```

so when I look for the user tablespace, it return only the above two tablespaces as expected:

```
select default_tablespace from user_users;
```

However, when I log in as this user and check the owner of the objects:

```
SELECT owner, object_name, object_type FROM all_objects 
where owner = 'THE_OTHER_TEMP_USER';
```

It returns all the tables belonging to THE_OTHER_TEMP_USER, and all those tables are from a very different tablespace!!

However, when I log in as THE_OTHER_TEMP_USER and run above command again but with different condition...

```
SELECT owner, object_name, object_type FROM all_objects 
where owner = 'TEMP_USER';
```

...it returns nothing.

What is the explanation for such behavior?

Comment: A tablespace in oracle is not an access control construct. In fact its not a logical construct, only a physical. So as long as you have granted permissions on a schema or table you can access it, no matter in which tablespace it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tablespaces have nothing whatsoever to do with privileges.  The set of objects that a user has access to has nothing whatsoever to do with what tablespace those objects are in.  Tablespaces are only a way of logically partitioning storage.

`all_objects` show all the objects that the current user has access to.  That is the set of objects that the user owns as well as any objects that the user has been granted access to via `GRANT` statements.  Based on what you are saying, `TEMP_USER` has been granted access to many objects owned by `THE_OTHER_TEMP_USER` (directly or via a role) while `THE_OTHER_TEMP_USER` has not been granted access to any of `TEMP_USER`'s objects.

You could, of course, issue `REVOKE` statements that would revoke the ability of `TEMP_USER` to access the various objects owned by `THE_OTHER_TEMP_USER`.